# Copy property value from matching objects between two arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I am using Angular 2 / Typescript.

I have an array of "Items":

```
items: [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "qty" undefined
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "qty" undefined
  } 
  {
    "id": 3,
    "qty" undefined
  }...etc
]
```

Then I have an array of "ItemsWithQuantities":

```
 itemsWithQuantities: [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "qty" 55
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "qty" 3
      } ...etc
    ]
```

I want to put the qty values from the `itemsWithQuantities` array into the qty property of the matching (by `id`) object in the `items` array. Obviously I could create a loop and nested loop to find a match and set the property value but I am more interested in a refactored/eloquent solution. I'm wondering if there is something built in to typescript/"new" JS flavors or even lodash that can get me what I want.

Comment: If the arrays are sorted then it's a simple iteration (if they are not, then sort them first, you won't be able to get a better solution).

Comment: Why don't you just make `items = itemsWithQuantities`?

Comment: @Redu  I guess this technically isn't an answer toward the actual question. But, I've been thinking this might be the better thing architecturally speaking.

But to answer yout question directly... my itemsWithQuantities objects don't "look" exactly the same as my items objects. Only an ID and a qty match.  Both objects have unique properties that don't exist on the other object. (plus the length of the arrays will be different: `items.length == 230` while `itemsWithQuantities.length == 5`) But regardless, I think I understand what you're saying

Comment: Well that's why it's a comment... Moreover if you want to break the referencing you can also do like `items = itemsWithQuantities.slice();`

Comment: Well ok then the question was not complete.. OK how about `itemsWithQuantities` having all objects of the `items` array with same ids and nothing else. I mean is there a one to one correlation between the array items?

Answer (score 1):

You can use lodash [merge](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#merge)!

```js
    var items = [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "qty": undefined
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "qty": undefined
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "qty": undefined
      }
    ];
    
    var itemsWithQuantities = [
          {
            "id": 1,
            "qty": 55
          },
          {
            "id": 2,
            "qty": 3
          },
          {
           "id": 3,
            "qty": 24
          }
    ];
        
    var answer = _.merge(itemsWithQuantities, items);
    console.log(answer);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.5.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lpq6huvw/210/)

Answer (score 0):

If all items of `items` and `itemsWithQuantity` arrays are correlated one to one then you may simply do like;

```js
var items    = [{"id": 1,"qty": undefined, "x": "something"}, {"id": 2,"qty": undefined, "x":"another thing"}, {"id": 3,"qty": undefined, "x": "whatever"}],
itemsWithQty = [{"id": 1,"qty": 3}, {"id": 2,"qty": 7}, {"id": 3,"qty": 4}],
result       = items.map((o,i) => Object.assign({},o,itemsWithQty[i]));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is indeed not the case that you could just assign one array to the other, then you could use the built in [.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?v=example) and [.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find?v=example) methods.

Example below (although at the end of the day, internally, it's still doing the loops you mentioned) :

```
 const res = items
    .map(item =>  Object.assign({}, item,{qty:(itemsWithQuantities.find(iwq => iwq.id === item.id) || {qty:0}).qty}));
```